# JSON Schema giving me validation errors for multipleOf 0.01 for any number ending in .49 or .99

Tags: json, node.js, jsonschema

I am using [JSON Schema](https://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/reference/numeric.html#number) to validate a server request and I have some values that I want validated to 2DP. I have used the following schema to validate these fields:

```
'properties': {
   'amount': {'type': ['number', 'null'], 'multipleOf': 0.01}
}
```

This works fine for all cases other than numbers ending in .49 or .99, where I get the error `amount is not a multiple of (divisible by) 0.01`.

This is presumably some kind of floating point error. If this is not right, how should I validate numbers to a certain precision?

Comment: I had to define option multipleOfPrecision in ajv https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv

Answer (score 2):

To avoid looping through and casting decimals as suggested above, I ended up writing a custom validator:

```
Validator.prototype.customFormats.currency = function(input) {
    if (input === undefined) { return true}
    return (input * 100) % 1 === 0
}
```